# Possible to set attributes of ActionViewClass through xml in Android Action Bar?

Tags: android, xml, menu, android-actionbar

I have the following menu xml code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
<item
    android:id="@+id/action_select_appshare"
    android:showAsAction="always"
    android:title="@string/action_select_appshare"
    android:actionViewClass="android.widget.Spinner" />

</menu>
```

Because a `Spinner` seem to require the definition of the `android:spinnerMode` attribute from the get-go, and there doesn't seem to be a proper way to set it later on after the `Spinner` object is created. I was wondering if there's a way to specify additional attributes (such as `android:spinnerMode` in my e.g.) for an `android:actionViewClass` within the menu XML?

Thanks!

Comment: Struggling here too!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally found it:

Related links: [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34378670/how-to-access-views-insde-the-actionlayout-in-menu), [2](https://developer.android.com/training/appbar/action-views.html) and [3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34378670/how-to-access-views-insde-the-actionlayout-in-menu)

1. Create a new res/layout file. Put the spinner in it, with all the properties you need/want. Note that the Spinner should be the root view.
2. In your menu file containing the actionClassProvider=spinner, remove actionClassProvider, and replace it with actionLayout="@layout/my_spinner"

All Done

I hope this helps somebody!

Answer (score 0):

well you could solve it in 2 ways: create a custom spinner and put what you want there, or, get the actionView when inflating this menuItem, and then do what you want with it.